# How can use a vector name as a variable?

Tags: c++

How would I use a vector function where the vector name is a variable? A rough sketch of what I'm referring to:

```
void someFunc(int x) {
    vector<int>v0;
    vector<int>v1;
    vector<int>v2;
    switch (x) {
    case 0: //var will be assigned v0
    case 1: //var will be assigned v1
    case 2: //var will be assigned v2
    }
    var.assign(10, 1); //eg. when x == 1, it will be v1.assign(10,1)
}
```

Comment: You could use a pointer or a reference, but this looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is your goal?

Comment: Yes, if I have a lot of code that's the same except for the vector name, I would rather just write it once.

Comment: "Yes, if I have a lot of code that's the same except for the vector name," normally you put that code into a function and pass a vector there by a reference

Comment: It could be, I suppose my goal is to avoid copy pasting the same code while only changing the vector name.

Comment: I think I've got the answer, I didn't realize you could have a pointer vector.

Comment: You could use an map of vectors, or an array of vectors, or even a vector of vectors...

Comment: Oh so it is sort of like sets in maths?

Comment: @JXkcd You can have a pointer to any type, including `void` which isn't a type that you can declare an object of.  The only thing you can't have a pointer to is a reference.  The pointer would point to the thing the reference refers to, not the reference itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use a pointer.  In the switch statement you assign to the pointer the vector and then afterword you just access the assigned vector through that pointer.  That would look like

```
void someFunc(int x) {
    vector<int> v0;
    vector<int> v1;
    vector<int> v2;
    vector<int>* var;
    switch (x) {
    case 0: var = &v0; break;
    case 1: var = &v1; break;
    case 2: var = &v2; break;
    }
    var->assign(10, 1); //eg. when x == 1, it will be v1.assign(10,1)
}
```

Comment: @Jabberwocky Considering the function the OP had was just a sketch I was taking the example to mean they were disparate vectors so I kept them separate.  If they are indeed something that should be in a array then that would be the go to solution.

Comment: Good point, but having  disparate vectors looks like bad desgn to me.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I don't think we have anywhere near enough information to come to that conclusion. There is any number of reasons why you may wish to pick from a load of different vectors, with them being identified in some manner other than numerically and contiguously. An array _may_ be the best solution here, but otherwise this is the go-to general solution. In other words: you're both right!

Answer (score 6):

Even simpler, you can use an array of vectors:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

void someFunc(int x) {
  array<vector<int>, 3> v;    // 3 vectors here (0..2), but we could as well
                              // have 100 vectors.
  v[x].assign(10, 1);
}
```